# I need to Hide SfCircularProgressBar but not inside content elements

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need to Hide SfCircularPr[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcSsr.png)progressBar but inside the content elements

I want to hide synfusion circualr progrss bar only not content with in crcular progrss bar. firstly, we don't display progrss bar we will dispaly content with in progrss bar

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.